# File execute permission

Tags: shell, ubuntu, terminal, permissions

```
lameta01dev:/tmp/test> ls -ltra
total 20
drwxrwxrwt 14 root root 12288 2016-08-29 14:21 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    19 2016-08-29 14:24 a.sh
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 2016-08-29 14:24 .
lameta01dev:/tmp/test> whoami
apgimage
lameta01dev:/tmp/test> sh a.sh 
hello world
```

Question: If I am logged in as apgimage how am I able to extcute a.sh using "sh a.sh" command when owner of the file is root ?

Answer (score 1):

To run

```
sh a.sh
```

you need (a) *execute* permission on `sh` and (b) *read* permission on `a.sh`.

---

The *execute* permission on `a.sh` determines whether the following will succeed or fail:

```
./a.sh
```

---

Notes:

1. As long as a user have read permission on `a.sh`, preventing `sh a.sh` does nothing for security: the user could just copy the contents of `a.sh` to his own file and set the execute bit on his copy.
2. To prevent a normal user from executing a script via `sh a.sh`, root can remove that file's read/write/execute permission for "other":

   ```
   chmod o-a a.sh
   ```

   If the file is owned by a group that the normal user belongs to, then it will also be necessary to remove group permissions:

   ```
   chmod go-a a.sh
   ```

Comment: What kind of security is this, I am able to perform execution using sh command overriding whole permissions set.

Comment: As long as you have _read_ permission on `a.sh`, preventing `sh a.sh` does nothing for security : you could just copy the contents of `a.sh` to your own file and set the _execute_ bit on your copy.

Comment: Can root user override permissions of normal user ?  I found that for a file which has no permissions "----------  1 apgimage root    19 2016-08-29 14:24 a.sh" I couldnt do anything as apaimage but whenI logged in as root I was able to read, write but couldn't execute.

Comment: Yes, that works.  If the script belongs to root and root denies you read permission, then you cannot execute it.  If root runs `chmod go-a filename` then all permission to others (not user root) to read, write, or execute a file will be gone.

Comment: But if the file belongs to non root user and permission set looks like -rwx------ for that user, in that case it appears that root is falling under others permission which is --- but I was able to read, write but not execute the file.

Comment: @user204069 Yes, root is a special case: I don't think that there is anything you can do to prevent root from reading a file.